# Supplier Costs Minimization

Tags: optimization

I have a warehouse. The customer makes some orders and I have to make a correspondent order to the supplier. Than when the item arrives I will dispatch the item to the customer. I would optimize the process, e.g. **minimizing the shipping costs**. For example, I would like to decrease the shipping costs from the supplier and make batches of orders when I know that the item is very popular. Obviosuly, the optimization must take into account the size of the warehouse. MILP? May I consider the  "popularity" of an item as parameter?

Comment: Which kind model are you thinking of? Post an example and we can look what part has to be adjusted in order to regard the popularity of items.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, MILP. Also look up Network Transshipment problems.
To incorporate 'popularity' you might have to formalize (as a formula) how popularity is incorporated into the demands or the orders.

Comment: thnk you. popularity, in my opinion, would be just a probability (in bayes terms, maybe). I will try to make a formula.